# How to activate infrared mode on camera

Tags: camera

I have an [IR-CUT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKCGX1Z) camera module. I have an external IR LED source on. How do I explicitly activate similar "night mode" for my camera module?

If I have all of the lights off, I can take a picture in the dark and see the IR light. "Night mode" comes on automatically.

[image: dark]

If I turn the lights on, I don't see the IR light. "Night mode" is off.

[image: light]

If I have low light, "night mode" doesn't come on. I would like to be able to turn night mode on like in the first example.

[image]

Comment: Hi @joels, Wellcome and Nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. You can do it using python: (1) ArduCAM NOIR Raspberry Pi camera with Motorized IR Cut Filter Published by arducam19 on August 12, 2017/:
https://www.arducam.com/arducam-noir-raspberry-pi-camera-motorized-ir-cut-filter/. Good luck and cheers.